# Зачем в Spring Boot + Hibernate использовать аннотацию @Transactional?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Использую `Spring Boot` + `Hibernate`.
Запросы в `DAO` слое выполняю с помощью `EntityManager`.

Почему без использования аннотации `@Transactional` при выполнение запроса я получаю ошибку о том, что `ResultSet` уже закрыт:

```
2021-11-01 12:06:44.237  WARN 5084 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
2021-11-01 12:06:44.237 ERROR 5084 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
2021-11-01 12:06:44.250 ERROR 5084 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not advance using next(); nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

`EntityManager` использую в слое DAO так, бин, как таковой, не создаю:

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Пример запроса:

```java
private static final String FIND_ALL_GIFT_CERTIFICATES_SQL = "SELECT gc FROM GiftCertificate AS gc";

@Override
    public Set<GiftCertificate> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery(FIND_ALL_GIFT_CERTIFICATES_SQL, GiftCertificate.class)
                .getResultStream()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.prog.gc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gift_certificates_system</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>controller</module>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>repository</module>
        <module>service</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <!-- Project encoding -->
        <esm.encoding>UTF-8</esm.encoding>

        <!-- Project properties -->
        <esm.groupId>com.prog.gc</esm.groupId>
        <esm.artifactId>gift_certificates_system</esm.artifactId>
        <esm.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</esm.version>

        <!-- Module properties -->
        <esm.module.model.artifactId>model</esm.module.model.artifactId>
        <esm.module.repository.artifactId>repository</esm.module.repository.artifactId>
        <esm.module.service.artifactId>service</esm.module.service.artifactId>
        <esm.module.controller.artifactId>controller</esm.module.controller.artifactId>

        <!-- Dependency properties -->
        <maven.compiler.version>8</maven.compiler.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <jetbrains.annotation.version>22.0.0</jetbrains.annotation.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.14.1</log4j2.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>4.0.0</mockito.version>
        <h2database.version>1.4.200</h2database.version>
        <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>7.0.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
        <mysql.connectior.version>8.0.26</mysql.connectior.version>
        <hikaricp.version>4.0.3</hikaricp.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>

                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency> <!-- For ObjectUtils -->
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
                <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
                <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jetbrains.annotation.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2database.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql.connectior.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE:**
Открываем `javax.persistence` и смотрим на `public interface TypedQuery<X> extends Query {...}`:

```java
default Stream<X> getResultStream() {
        return getResultList().stream();
}

List<X> getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultSet` - это просто курсор, который перебирает строки на сервере БД (конечно, некоторое кэширование он тоже может делать).

Ты возвращаешь `Stream`, который тоже ленивый.

Соответственно, чтение из курсора в твоём коде начинается здесь `collect(toSet())`. К этому времени `Connection` уже закрыт, потому что ты не предпринял никаких действий для удержания его открытым. Аннотация `Transactional` как раз открывает коннект и удерживает его открытым, пока ты находишься внутри метода.

Непонятно, зачем ты вообще зовёшь ленивый `getResultStream`, если его ленивость никак не используешь. Зови сразу `getResultList`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. `getResultList` возвращает `List<T>`, а у меня метод возвращает `Set<T>`, поэтому сначала вызываю `getResultStream`. Тем более внутри `getResultStream` - это тотже `getResultList` только со стримом `getResultList.stream()`. Не могли бы вы объяснить на примере исходного кода аннотации `@Transactioanl` + Hibernate как это выполнялется?

Comment: > Тем более внутри getResultStream - это тотже getResultList только со стримом

Это где так? Добавь в вопрос свой pom.xml или что там у тебя. 

>  у меня метод возвращает Set<T>

У тебя в базе есть дубликаты подарочных сертификатов? Иначе зачем ты `Set` возвращаешь?

Comment: Добавил в топик `pom.xml` + ответ на вопрос (тут не влезет, всё в одну строку преобразуется)

Comment: В интерфейсе просто дефолтная имплементация для провайдеров, которые не умеют ленивый поток возвращать. Хибернэйт умеет, вроде как